# Does the Robertson uncertainty relation concern the same quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Does the Robertson uncertainty relation concern the same quantum system? Ie. should the observables $ A, B$ be measured on the same system or can they be measured on two *independent* systems?

I have came across a textbook that states that if we consider the same quantum system then the 1/2 factor is not needed. Is this correct?

Also, in this context what does *simultaneously* mean when referring to measurement of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I think what you're referring to is the Arthurs and Kelly version of the uncertainty relation for joint measurements, which does produce a lower bound of $\hbar$ rather than $\frac{1}{2}\hbar$.  The most accessible reference on this is  Raymer, M. G. "Uncertainty principle for joint measurement of noncommuting variables." American journal of physics 62.11 (1994): 986-993.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! If you have enough background on this, you might want to post an answer as well?

Comment: Unfortunately for you I don't have time right now.  The original papers by Arthurs and Kelly (Ref.4 in Raymer's paper) is difficult to find.  The argument is also repeated very clearly in a paper by Stig Stegholm (Ref.6 in Raymer's paper).